# Stripe payment gateway - Connection Problem to the Web server ECLIPSE

Tags: java, runtime-error, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am currently using Eclipse to test out stripe payment. Unfortunately i do not have a SSL certificate. Is is possible to run without SSL at Eclipse? because i keep getting this error in my console. I was trying on creating a charge at Stripe but the response of the stripe API charge did not pop out..I am assuming it might could be the connection problem between stripe and my servlet.

---

```
com.stripe.exception.ApiConnectionException: IOException during API request to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com): api.stripe.com Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists,you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com.
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.makeUrlConnectionRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:442)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.getStripeResponse(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:580)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.rawRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:499)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.staticRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:524)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:81)
    at com.stripe.net.ApiResource.request(ApiResource.java:195)
    at com.stripe.model.Customer.create(Customer.java:130)
    at com.stripe.model.Customer.create(Customer.java:122)
    at testing.Payment.doGet(Payment.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.stripe.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.createPostConnection(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:239)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.makeUrlConnectionRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:414)
    ... 32 more
com.stripe.exception.ApiConnectionException: IOException during API request to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com): api.stripe.com Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists,you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com.
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.makeUrlConnectionRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:442)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.getStripeResponse(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:580)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.rawRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:499)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.staticRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:524)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:81)
    at com.stripe.net.ApiResource.request(ApiResource.java:195)
    at com.stripe.model.Charge.create(Charge.java:372)
    at com.stripe.model.Charge.create(Charge.java:364)
    at testing.Payment.doGet(Payment.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.stripe.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.createPostConnection(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:239)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.makeUrlConnectionRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:414)
    ... 32 more
```

My index jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Stripe Pay</title>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<style>
.StripeElement {
    background-color: white;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 15px 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
    transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
}

.StripeElement--focus {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
    border-color: #fa755a;
}

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}

.container {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 5px 20px 15px 20px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.col-50 {
    -ms-flex: 50%; /* IE10 */
    flex: 50%;
}

.col-75 {
    -ms-flex: 75%; /* IE10 */
    flex: 75%;
}

.col-50, .col-75 {
    padding: 0 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Payment</h2>
        <div class="col-75">
        <div class="container">
<form action="payment" method="post" id="payment-form">
             <div class="col-50">

                Address: <br> <input type="text" name="address" id= "address" placeholder="542 W.15 Street"> 
                    <br> 
                City:<br> <input type="text" name="city" id= "city" placeholder="New York"> 
                <br>
                State:<br> <input type="text" name="state" id= "state" placeholder="New York">
                    <br>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="card-element"> Credit or Debit card: </label>
                    <div id="card-element">
                        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->                    

                    </div>

                    <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
                    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                </div>

                <button>Submit Payment</button>
                <input type= "hidden" id="tokens" value="token">  
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p> Bank number : 4242 4242 4242 4242</p>
    <script>
        (function() {


            var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_uRcaa3vdG7sfD1m0SEwT5DnO');
            var elements = stripe.elements();
            var style = {
                base : {
                    // Add your base input styles here. For example:
                    fontSize : '16px',
                    color : "#32325d",
                    fontFamily : '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
                    fontSmoothing : 'antialiased',
                    '::placeholder' : {
                        color : '#aab7c4'
                    }
                },
                invalid : {
                    color : '#fa755a',
                    iconColor : '#fa755a'
                }
            };

            // Create an instance of the card Element.
            var card = elements.create('card', {
                style : style

            });




            // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
            card.mount('#card-element');

            card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
                var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                if (event.error) {
                    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
                } else {
                    displayError.textContent = '';
                }
            });     

            //Create a token to transmit card information
            var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
            form.addEventListener('submit',function(event) {
                var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
                var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
                var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
                event.preventDefault();
                    stripe.createToken(card,{address_line1:address,address_city:city,address_state:state,}).then(function(result) {
                    if (result.error) {
                    // Inform the customer that there was an error.
                    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
                    } else {
                    // Send the token to your server.
                    stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
                    }
                });
            });

            //Submit the token and the rest of your form to your server
            function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
                // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
                var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
                var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
                hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
                hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
                form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

                // Submit the form
                form.submit();
                var token = token.id;
                alert("Success! Token: " + token)
            }
        })();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

My Charge servlet

```
package testing;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.stripe.Stripe;
import com.stripe.exception.StripeException;
import com.stripe.model.Charge;
import com.stripe.model.Customer;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Payment
 */

public class Payment extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Payment() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_f9LqcocbUTzo75w4cODPmSWF";

         String token = request.getParameter("tokens");

         Map<String, Object> customerParameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         customerParameter.put("email", "a@gmail.com");
         try {
            Customer newCustomer = Customer.create(customerParameter);
        } catch (StripeException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chargeParams.put("amount", 2000);
        chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
        chargeParams.put("description", "Charge for Stripe Item");
        chargeParams.put("source", token );
        // ^ obtained with Stripe.js    


    try {
            Charge charge = Charge.create(chargeParams);

        } catch (StripeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(token));
    response.setContentType("text/html");//setting the content type  
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();//get the stream to write the data  

    //writing html in the stream  
    pw.println("<html><body>");  
    pw.println(chargeParams);  
    pw.println(gson.toJson(token)); 
    pw.println("</body></html>");  

    pw.close();//closing the stream  

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Apparently the stripe dashboard did not shown any created customer nor the charge was shown in my site. The only thing created in the Stripe dashboard developer Log was the record of the token.

Comment: That error has nothing to do with your SSL cert (which is for your server, and which you must have for production).  It means you failed to connect to the internet.

Comment: After i press submit for the Card Element Quickstart payment in JSP ( apparently i get to retrieve the token ID in the jsp page) yet the problem happens after the JSP page redirected to my servlet Charge file. Thank you fro the reply  @SLaks

Comment: I agree with @SLaks here.  Your code is simply not connecting to the internet, not having a bad handshake.  The initial tokenization request is coming from the browser (not the web server), whereas the second charge creation request is coming from the web server itself.  I suspect Eclipse is having trouble establishing a connection at all.  You might want to start there.

Comment: @korben is there any solution to connect my codes to the web server? I am a bit confuse about this.. I could run the internal web browser in Eclipse tho

Comment: is there anyone can help me with this? I am still facing the same trouble.. its not about the firewall problem and Eclipse is able to surf the web in the internal browser...